# Using XLOOKUP via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I ran into trouble running a bit more complex Excel XLOOKUP formula over VBA. I have a plain XLOOKUP running perfectly fine in both Excel spreadsheet as well as VBA:

```
=XLOOKUP(1234,Orders[Number],Orders[Comment],"",0,1)
MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup(1234, Range("Orders[Number]"), Range("Orders[Comment]"), "", 0, 1)
```

However I need to add one extra condition. It works fine in Excel spreadsheet:

```
=XLOOKUP(1234&9,Orders[Number]&Orders[Class],Orders[Comment],"",0,1)
```

But I can't manage to convert this to VBA code as the code below produces an error:

> Run-time error '13': Type mismatch error

The latest version I tried with was this. I have a feeling the problem is somehow concating the ranges?

```
MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup(1234 & 9, Range("Orders[Number]") & Range("Orders[Class]"), Range("Orders[Comment]"), "", 0, 1)
```

Comment: You can't do `Range("Orders[Number]") & Range("Orders[Class]")` because that attempts to concatenate two `Variant` arrays (there's an implicit `.Value`). The workaround is to use `Worksheet.Evaluate` and the worksheet-formula version within quotes. Or you can loop.

Comment: Thanks BigBen. Interesting, first time to come across `Evaluate`. While `Evaluate("XLOOKUP(1234&9,Orders[Number]&Orders[Class],Orders[Comment],"",0,1)")` still gave me the same error (Activesheet.Evalute asks for an object) some googling shows that square brackets do the same thing and this works for me. `MsgBox [XLOOKUP(1234&9,Orders[Number]&Orders[Class],Orders[Comment],"",0,1)]`

Comment: You needed to double up the inner quotes when using `Evaluate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See BigBen's comment for solution.